# ajax call not getting executed in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I m sending some checkbox which are selected,their value to next php page with ajax call.but in the above code i m not able to send it to ajax call

code is as below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_check_value() {
        var c_value = [];
        $('input[name="services"]:checked').each(function () {
            c_value.push(this.value);
        });
        return c_value.join(',');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
    alert("hi");
        //var os = $('#originState').val();
      \  //var c = $('#commodity').val();
        //var ds = $('#destState').val();
        var ser = get_check_value();
        //var queryString = "os=" + os;
        var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
        alert("hi");
       $.ajax({
       //alert("ajax");
        type: "POST",
        url: "sortingajax.php",
        data: "query=" + queryString,
        success: function (b) {
           // alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            $('#results').html(b);
            console.log(b);
        }
    });

  });
 });

</script>
<form name="searchForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="twic" />TWIC
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="enclosedTrucking" />Enclosed Trucking
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="flatBedTrucking" />Flat Bed Trucking
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code.When i select checkboxes from page,and on click of submit.i want to pass them to next php page with ajax call.but its not going to next page and no response is coming back....

Please help guysss

ajaxphp page

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
$query=$_GET['query'];
echo $query;
$countsql='SELECT * FROM XML';
    $countsql1=mysql_query($countsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($countsql1);  
$countArray2=array();
print($countsql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($countsql1)) {
    // Append to the array


    $countArray2[] = $row;



    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}

?>
<?php
foreach($countArray2 as $array)
{



?>
<div class="search">
hi
</div>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: where you are calling  get_check_value() function?

Comment: Is that `\\`` in your code a typo? And you need to do something with your `querystring` because that is an invalid way of sending data. Cause now you would have something like `data: "query=&ser=twic"`

Comment: Yeah that '\' is breaking the script. Also, to determine if your script is working, you should post the contents of sortingajax.php.

Comment: I removed '\',but didnt make any difference,and i pasted the ajaxpage as well.please check sir.

Comment: You have to handle form's `submit` event instead of button's `click`:
`$('form[name="searchForm"]').on('click', function () { ... }`. Also you have to call `preventDefault` inside handler.

Answer (score 1):

`data: "query=" + queryString,` is wrong because the `"query=" +` is a syntax error. It should be:

```
 var queryString = "os="+os+"&ser="+ser;
```

and then

```
 data : queryString,
```

Or you can format it like:

```
  data : {
      'ser' : ser,
      'os'  : os
 }
```

Then there is the fact that your Ajax is using POST but you're trying to read the request with $_GET rather than $_POST or $_REQUEST in your PHP.

Comment: That's not true. `data` option may be a query string (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Not when you're using POST.

Comment: POST or GET you can use a query string

Comment: @developerwjk Are you sure? Any proof?

Comment: i replaced as u showed sir.but when i m clicking on submit button,it just appends the checkboxes in the url,but doesnot changes the content .help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "appending the checkboxes value to url"?

Comment: @Musa, Ok, you were right. You can use a querystring with POST, but you don't include "query=" with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these two amends:

```
var data : "?ser=" + ser; // put '?' instead of '&'
```

Or more jQuery way:

```
 data : { ser : ser },
```

---

And you are missing the `dataType` in your ajax:

```
dataType :  'html',
```

---

On the php side, as this is a post request, so you have to put this:

```
$query=$_POST['ser'];
```

Comment: i tried this sir ,but when i m clicking on submit button,its just appending the checkboxes value to url.not going for ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're forgetting to prevent the Submit button default behavior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_check_value() {
    var c_value = [];
    $('input[name="services"]:checked').each(function () {
        c_value.push(this.value);
    });
    return c_value.join(',');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (evt) {

evt.preventDefault();

alert("hi");
    //var os = $('#originState').val();
  \  //var c = $('#commodity').val();
    //var ds = $('#destState').val();
    var ser = get_check_value();
    //var queryString = "os=" + os;
    var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
    alert("hi");
   $.ajax({
   //alert("ajax");
    type: "POST",
    url: "sortingajax.php",
    data: "query=" + queryString,
    success: function (b) {
       // alert(a+' ok. '+b)
        $('#results').html(b);
        console.log(b);
    }
});

  });
 });

</script>
```